# Jscrollpane & Bootstrap modal not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal from bootstrap that i've implemented on the site. 
Problem is that I need to change the default scrollbar from the overflow css to a jscrollpane so I can customize the scrollbars. It worked okay on  but I can't put it right on a modal

HTML

```
<div class="modal fade" id="SdanK" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="SdanKLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                &times;
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="SdanKLabel">
                Terms & Conditions
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body scroll-pane">
            <p>This is Photoshop's version  of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus a sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit.<br/><br/>

                Nam nec tellus a odio tincidunt auctor a ornare odio. Sed non  mauris vitae erat consequat auctor eu in elit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris in erat justo. Nullam ac urna eu felis dapibus condimentum sit amet a augue. Sed non neque elit. Sed ut imperdiet nisi. Proin condimentum fermentum nunc. Etiam pharetra, erat sed fermentum feugiat, velit mauris egestas quam, ut aliquam massa nisl quis neque. Suspendisse in orci enim.<br/><br/>

                This is Photoshop's version  of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus a sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit.<br/><br/>

                Nam nec tellus a odio tincidunt auctor a ornare odio. Sed non  mauris vitae erat consequat auctor eu in elit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris in erat justo. Nullam ac urna eu felis dapibus condimentum sit amet a augue. Sed non neque elit. Sed ut imperdiet nisi. Proin condimentum fermentum nunc. Etiam pharetra, erat sed fermentum feugiat, velit mauris egestas quam, ut aliquam massa nisl quis neque. Suspendisse in orci enim.<br/><br/>

                This is Photoshop's version  of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus a sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit.<br/><br/>

                This is Photoshop's version  of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus a sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit.<br/><br/>

                Nam nec tellus a odio tincidunt auctor a ornare odio. Sed non  mauris vitae erat consequat auctor eu in elit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris in erat justo. Nullam ac urna eu felis dapibus condimentum sit amet a augue. Sed non neque elit. Sed ut imperdiet nisi. Proin condimentum fermentum nunc. Etiam pharetra, erat sed fermentum feugiat, velit mauris egestas quam, ut aliquam massa nisl quis neque. Suspendisse in orci enim.<br/></p>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div>
```

And the jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(function()
    {
        $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
    });
});
```

CSS

```
.scroll-pane
{
    width: 885px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
.horizontal-only
{
    height: auto;
    max-height: 600px;
}

.scroll-pane .jspContainer .jspVerticalBar .jspTrack .jspDrag {
    background: url(../images/scrollbar-middle.png);
}
.scroll-pane .jspContainer .jspVerticalBar .jspTrack {
    background: url(../images/scrollbar-behind.png);
}
.scroll-pane .jspContainer .jspVerticalBar  {
    background: none;
}
```

Again, it worked on other elements, why can't it work in the modal?
Please provide solution, and thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

i have just created working demo for you.

```
$(function() {
  $('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) { // This event fires immediately when the show instance method is called. If caused by a click, the clicked element is available as the relatedTarget property of the event.
    $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane(); 
  });
});
```

**Working Demo**

http://jsbin.com/mumehesa/1/edit

Comment: Still does not work for me. And this time my overflow didn't change to hidden. And the jspContainer etc isn't showing up at all. BTW : I have 2 modals that have the same scrollpane function, if that makes a difference